# Does not work to rename the postal code and city label fields from WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, hook-woocommerce, billing

I tried for more then 3 hours to change and to remove the red star* from the postal code, but does not work
here is my code in functions.php, using a child theme

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'change_billing_codpostal_checkout' );
function change_billing_codpostal_checkout( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['placeholder'] = 'Introduceti codul postal';
    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['label'] = 'CodPostal';
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'change_billing_city_checkout' );
function change_billing_city_checkout( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['placeholder'] = 'Adaugati Localitatea';
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['label'] = 'Localitate';
    return $fields;
}
```

The placeholders from both works... and is showing me the well words

and for remove the require - is work but it still show me the red star and i want to display that..

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'wc_optional_billing_fields_camp', 20, 1 );
function wc_optional_billing_fields_camp( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing_postcode']['required'] = false;
    return $fields;
}
```

Also I want to rename the "Shipping" for checkout page with other word but doesnt work...

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'customizing_checkout_text_shipping', 42, 3 );
function customizing_checkout_text_shipping( $translated_text_shipping, $untranslated_text_shipping, $domain )
{
    if ( $untranslated_text_shipping == 'Shipping' && is_checkout() ) {
        $translated_text_shipping = __( 'Transport', $domain );
    }
    return $translated_text_shipping;
}
```

Comment: No one? can give me a answer, please I dont know that to do, I tried all the varieties but not one works... only to this works "Shipping" and also "Town/ city" and "Postcode / ZIP" .....

Answer (score 0):

try this hope this work

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'remove_postcode_validation', 99 );

    function remove_postcode_validation( $fields ) {

        unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['validate']);
        unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode']['validate']);

        return $fields;
    }
```

Comment: does not work, the red start is stilling there, so maybe I need to change the class the ''abbr'' ??? also the name does not change

Comment: try this -// Add this to your functions.php
 
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_reply');
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_reply');
  
function translate_reply($translated) {
$translated = str_ireplace('Shipping and Handling', 'Postage & Packaging', $translated);
return $translated;
}

Comment: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-edit-translate-shipping-handling-cart-checkout-page/

Comment: check this link

Comment: you can change name by jquery or by going into plugin files

Comment: can you show me how i can do this things using jquery, because i dont want to install other plugin

Comment: your website url

Comment: and also check this link hope this will help you https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

Comment: give me a exemple please

Comment: tell me ur website url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150468/discussion-between-alcatraz007-and-prince).